# Is it possible to get an exported WP site in a zipped folder up and running?

Tags: migration, export

Our old webmaster abandoned us and stopped hosting our website. All he gave us to work with was a zipped folder of the website. It contains the wp-admin, wp-content, and wp-includes folders, index.php, and 26 other php files in the root of the folder. We don't have any access to the server it was installed on, but we do still own the domain name. Is it possible to get this up and running, or is this just junk now?

Comment: Did you receive a Database (SQL) file too?

Comment: No, no .sql files.

Comment: With no database backup, the content of your site is gone. I would suggest looking for any .sql, .sql.gz, or .zip files that might contain your database. With this and your files, a restore is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not junk, but it's not complete. You should also have the database, normally an `.sql` (can also be zipped).

You should buy hosting, change the DNS to point to your new host. Than you want to upload the files he gave you to the new server and import the contents of your old database into the new one. If all goes well, your site will be up and running by this time.

You should, however, have someone familiar with WordPress do this.

Comment: So perhaps a better question would be, if I have the WP folders I mentioned but not the SQL database, is it better to try to recover the site or start over from scratch (for a site of, say, 20 pages)

Answer (score 0):

just pay him whatever he asked and you avoided paying before and ask him to help you migrate to a new host, or sue his pants off.

It is your responsibility as the owner of the site to have a backup and recovery plan to the not unheard of event of malware take over, hardware failure, power down, or personal illness that might happen to your servrers or administrators. This should not be an after thought, it is a basic requirement for any site which has cost time and effort to make.

And no, based on your description those files are not enough to get the site running, you will need also the sql files of the database. You might also need to know what was the server enviroment on which your site was running, some hostings do funny things and have some essential configuration outside of the wordpress directories.

*I had a client that more then a year after I setup a site for him asked me if I have a backup for the site, apparently he ignored the requests of the hosting company to pay for the hosting for the following year and not surprisingly they erased his account.

Answer (score 0):

Hosing platforms like wpengine (one of the examples) have helpful guide to exporting sites from old server to there server, similarly many other specific WP hosting companies also provide services at some additional cost to migrate/setup your site. 
But yes as everyone mentioned you would need your DB file (SQL) along with all the other files your previous developer gave you.